# How to install splash on Windows 10? I need it for scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU8aA.png)I began to use scrapy for web scraping for a month and recently I need to get some info from js, and it seems that scrapy-splash is a good idea but I stuck on the installation as my platform is Windows.

I followed the doc of splash to install it manually on Bash on Windows. However, the module pyqt4 refers to an error and I don't know how to change the installation file if it's out-dated. Then I tried Docker on Windows but the image only supports the linux container, not the Windows container and the system sent an error when I tried switching to the Linux container. Hence I'll appreciate you if any solution is given.

Comment: It'd be good if we knew what the error that pyqt4 refers to. Please provide this information.

Comment: @musikreck thx, I have submitted the image to the description.

Comment: No problem. From a quick Google search, using `apt-cache search libpng12-dev` will show you what packages are making reference to your `libpng12-dev` package. In terms of actually satisfying the dependency, the same post suggests using `apt-get update`. I'm referring to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391184/but-is-referred-to-by-another-package-finding-that-package).

Comment: @musikreck I have swtiched to a pure linux system anyway but you taught me something to deal with linux-app installation.thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)